# If all the linear functionals are bounded, can we say the space is a Hilbert Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

3. If z is any fixed element of an inner product space $X$, show that $f(x) = \langle x,z \rangle $ defines a bounded linear functional f on X, of norm $||z||$.
4. Consider Prob. 3. If the mapping $X \to X^\prime$ given by $z \mapsto f$ is surjective, show that $X$ must be a Hilbert space.

I am working on problem 4 above. I just completed problem 3 which shows the linear functional defined is bounded. Now problem 4 states the mapping is surjective which means every linear functional is of the same form so they are all bounded, but I don't see how we can conclude from this that we have a Hilbert space. Is there any relevant theorem that relates functionals to Hilbert space. The Riesz Representation theorem states that all bounded linear functional can be represented by an inner product, but I don't think it says anything about the converse.

Comment: My recollection:  Inner product space is a Hilbert space if it is complete (Cauchy sequence limit is in the space).

Comment: In problem 4, $X'$ denotes the space of *bounded* linear functionals on $X$.  So there is no assertion that every linear functional is bounded; it's only talking about the bounded ones.

Answer (score 4):

You need to show that $X$ is complete. That is, any Cauchy sequence is convergent. By part 3, if $\{x_n\}\subset X$ is Cauchy, you get a corresponding sequence $\{\hat x_n\}\subset X'$. As the dual is always complete, there exists $f\in X'$ such that $\hat x_n\to f$. By the surjectivity, there exists $x\in X$ with $f=\hat x$. Now it remains to prove that $x_n\to x$.